# Which front end technology with Java EE backend

Tags: java, frontend, backend

There are so many languages in web development that sometime I get confused which one to learn and start with. I like Java, but dont like JSP for presentation, are there any front-end technologies that best suits with Java/Java EE backend for web application development?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the most up-to-date way to write Java web applications and web-based front-end ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703656/what-is-the-most-up-to-date-way-to-write-java-web-applications-and-web-based-fron)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The web-layer technology that is promoted in recent JavaEE versions is [JSF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/javaserverfaces-139869.html). It uses facelets instead of JSP for its views.

JSP with JSTL is pretty fine though, I don't see a reason to drop it. You can use it with any web framework, like spring-mvc, struts, or other frameworks with different rendering technologies like GWT, Vaadin, Wicket, etc.

Comment: Actually, wicket doesn't use JSP.  They can be used together, but it's a bit unnatural.

Comment: thanks, I was just listing frameworks with the idea that you can use any web framework with JaveEE. I'll rephrase a bit.

Answer (score 9):

With most things it depends on what your project requires. Here are two powerful web techologies you may find useful.

### Vaadin (Front and backend integrated as pure Java)

For rich, AJAX heavy applications **[Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/demo)** can be a great fit.

Advantages:
- Rapid development for complex interaction between UI components and backend beans
- Pure Java solution, no need to worry about creating markup or maintaining massive javascript files
- Good documentation
- Many powerful components out of the box and through the open source community

Disadvantages:
- There can be a steep learning curve to understand the various components
- Extending/changing some features (such as how a UI table retrieves data from a data source) can be very difficult
- If your application needs to be highly scalable, keep in mind this framework is stateful
- Handling back button on browser and dynamic URLs is extra work

### Spring MVC (Front is JSP or HTML, backend is Spring MVC)

If you want to maintain total control and scalability, **Spring MVC** with or without JSP is your best bet. Here's a good [hello world](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/) and more spring mvc tutorials are available on that site.

Advantages:

- Relies primarily on open standards
- Highly scalable
- Helps enforce proper MVC in your code
- RESTful framework, allows the developer to easily handle dynamic URLS and GET/POST separately
- Retain total control by creating the HTML/CSS/JS

> Note: For a HTML/CSS/JS solution, I recommend starting with something like **Zurb Foundation** or **Twitter Bootstrap**. It will save a lot of time compared to starting from scratch. Download the latest and import it into your webapp folder to get a quick boost on your project.  
>   
>   Disadvantages:
>   - Managing AJAX calls can become challenging on large applications
>   - A more indepth knowledge of HTML/CSS/JS will be required (compared to Vaadin)

Answer (score 0):

I think Spring MVC with ExtJS is the best option as ExtJS MVC really make the code readable and easy to manage. Similarly, IC of spring MVC will also make life easier for developer. I would recommend to look into Play framework. Play for java is good but if you want to dig more then obviously it will give you hard time as it mainly developed for Scala.

Answer (score -1):

Depending of the front end type you want to write, there are several options. If you can accept the style and model, have a look at SmartGWT. if you want a more GMail-like experience plain GWT 2.2 is pretty nice.